# VBA Select Multiple Columns In Union

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below spread sheet and in VBA I want to select the Ticker column and the Reference Price column based on those headers.

[image]

This is what I tried so far but I am only getting the Ticker values when I loop through the range.

```
 Dim rngRefData As Range
 Set rngRefData = Union(rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Ticker"), rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Reference Price"))
 Set rngRefData = Range(rngRefData, rngRefData.End(xlDown))

 For Each Item In rngRefData
      Debug.Print Item
 Next Item
```

How do I select both the entire Ticker column to the last value and the entire Reference Price column to the last value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could resize the range to the number of rows of data.

Btw it's not good practice to chain like that - if you don't Find the values your code will error so first check that the terms are found.

```
Sub x()

Dim rngRefData As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
 
r = rdWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set r1 = rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Ticker")  'and good practice to specify parameters
Set r2 = rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Reference Price")

If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing Then
    Set rngRefData = Union(r1.Resize(r), r2.Resize(r))
End If

For r = 1 To rngRefData.Rows.Count
    MsgBox rngRefData.Areas(1)(r) & " " & rngRefData.Areas(2)(r)
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked but is there a way to get it to print out as Ticker then Price.
Example:
A US Equity
99.73
AACAY US Equity
6
ect...

Comment: You don't need to combine the ranges to do that, just loop through each row.

Comment: I've changed the loop at the end to go through each row and put the results in a message box, so you can no doubt adapt that to suit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the both columns together in a adjacent range you can do it using Advanced Filter.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Range("B4:E12").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Range("G4:H4"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try in this way:

```
Set rngRefData = Union(rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Ticker").EntireColumn, rdWS.Range("1:1").Find("Reference Price").EntireColumn)
Set rngRefData = Intersect(rdWS.UsedRange, rngRefData)
Debug.Print rngRefData.Address

rngRefData.Copy rdWS.Range("K1")
```

and comment:

```
'Set rngRefData = Range(rngRefData, rngRefData.End(xlDown))
```